# MySQL connection codeigniter

Tags: mysql

Alright I am getting frustrated here with this mysql connection. I have the proper hostname, username, and password. I can connection via mysql workbench so my hostname should be accepted but getting an error when trying to view page

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the port is the right one and if you have restricted the ip which can connect to your database.